# jQuery / Get numbers from a string

Tags: jquery

I have a button on my page with a class of `comment_like` and an ID like `comment_like_123456` but the numbers at the end are variable; could be 1 to 1000000.

When this button is clicked, I need to grab the end number so I can run tasks on other elements with the same suffix.

Is there an easy way of grabbing this number in jQuery?

```
$('.comment_like').click(function() {
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');

    // grab number from element ID

    // do stuff with that number

});
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
var suffix = 'comment_like_123456'.match(/\d+/); // 123456
```

With respect to button:

```
$('.comment_like').click(function(){
  var suffix = this.id.match(/\d+/); // 123456
});
```

Comment: what if 
var suffix= '(123) 131-2312';

Comment: @Swaraj In that case, if you want just the last series of digits, you can use this regular expression where the dollar sign means that the pattern must be at the end of the string: /\d+$/

Answer (score 19):

You can try this. it will extract all number from any type of string.

```
var suffix = 'comment_like_6846511';
alert(suffix.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ANJYR/h1n3q45y/1/)**

Answer (score 15):

In your click handler:

```
var number = $(this).attr('id').split('_').pop();
```

Comment: As long as number always comes at end with an underscore before. Tightly coupled as long as html or requirements do not change :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a task for plain-old regular expressions, it has nothing to do with jQuery:

```
"comment_like_123456".match(/\d+/)

=> ["123456"]
```

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/hj2nJ/

```
var x = 'comment_like_6846511';
var y = '';

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    if ("" + parseInt(x[i]) != "NaN") //if the character is a number
        y = y + x[i];
}

document.write(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not a magic bullet. Use Javascript!

```
var temp = "comment_like_123456".split("_")
alert(temp[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be the easiest way to grab number from a string using jquery.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.comment_like').click(function() {
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var number = element_id.match(/\d+/);
    
    alert(number);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='comment_like' id='comment_like_123456'>Click Me To Get a number from string</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the id and run it through a regex.

```
$(mybutton).click(function() {
    var num = parseInt(/^.*\_(\d+)$/.exec(this.id)[1])
});
```

Comment: what's [1] here after exec?

Comment: @user938363 It gets the first capturing group in the matched string (i.e. everything between the first set of parenthesis, what was matched by the `\d+` - a number)