# Format numeric characters within a string

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Can someone please help me with a script that will reformat numeric character within a string from like "this is my mobile number 3456353433" to " This is my mobile number 3456 353 433". i will appreciate if it can likewise come with a functionality that tests if the string contains numeric character of 10 digits then pops up with a jquery dialog box asking if the user desires the mobile number to be reformatted. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, are you trying to do this in JavaScript, asp.net, or vb.net?

Comment: i was trying to do it in vb.net and javascript, but  the challenge with my script is at the point where javascript dialog box pops up asking if the client desires  to reformat the numeric character in the string, the javascript is not waiting for the client to respond . it just goes ahead and run the following script

Answer (score 2):

One way using jquery

```
<a class="fix">This is my mobile number 3456353433</a>
```

**Code**

```
$(function() {

var data = $('.fix').text();
var arr = data.split(' ');

//check if numeric and 10 numbers

if (isNaN(arr[5]) == false && arr[5].length == 10) {

//show popup, if yes run the format function

format();

}

function format() {

var first = arr[5].substring(0,4);
var second = arr[5].substring(4,20);
second = second.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1 ")

$('.fix').text("This is my mobile number "+ first+" "+second);

}

});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vLk8o7ff/)

Comment: Are you assuming that the number is always the 6th work in the string? I'm not sure that is what the OP intended.

Comment: @Blackwood -- i just went by "reformat numeric character within a string from like "This is my mobile number 3456353433" to " This is my mobile number 3456 353 433" and all the other bits in the Q. if (within a string from like) is an example then i provided an example on how to that.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm just suggesting that any other examples seem unlikely to have 5 words followed by a number. The OP really needs to explain what the rules are.

Comment: @Blackwood  --  the Q is all in one block of text and its a bit hard to grasp.  :)

Comment: Thank you, yes, please i will appreciate if the position of the number is treated as a variable. That is it might be in the 6th position or not.

Comment: @Pope -- the Q is put on hold -- can you reword the Q with exactly what you need to make it clearer

Comment: @ Tasos-- it assumed that the numeric character- 3456353433, we intend to reformat  will be the always be in the 6th position of the string i.e "This is my mobile number 3456353433" . The question is a how do edit the script so that it will reformat the numeric variable in a string even if the string is "I will like to  give you my mobile number . it is 3456353433". or even if the string is longer

Comment: that is, as Blackwood noted, how will it work as there are posibilities of having more than 5 words followed by a number ?

Comment: @Pope -- count the words if you dont know -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752853/how-to-count-words-in-javascript-using-jquery -- you could also get the numbers only in a string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282935/jquery-get-numbers-from-a-string